# open source c# library for ECEF to WGS84 velocity (ground speed)

Tags: velocity, wgs84

does anyone know where I can find a open source c# library that does the conversion from 3D cartesian (ECEF, earth-centered, earth-fixed) linear velocity to geodetic WGS84 ground speed? or an article that tells me the straight forward calculations will help too.

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for the same thing and came up to the conclusion, that the WGS84 velocity actually meant (for me at least), the speed in ENU coordinates; that is the East, North and Up components of the speed on the *tangential plane of the WGS84 ellipsoid*.

I also managed to write code to calculate this from the ECEF velocities. What I needed was actually the X,Y,Z positions (in ECEF coordinates) and X,Y,Z velocities (in ECEF coordinates). The steps were

#### 1) Calculate the location in Wgs84 coordinates (lat, lon, alt)

ECEF (X,Y,Z) to Wgs84 (lat, lon, alt) is not the easiest conversion, but I used the [Wikipedia "Heikkinen" equations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geographic_coordinate_conversion) and managed to get the script convert coordinates back and forth without losses in accuracy (checked that code works).

#### 2) Convert the speed from ECEF to ENU (Wgs84 tangential plane)

For the ECEF to ENU (or NED) coordinate conversion, there are multiple internet sources.
One good source was the [navipedia.](https://gssc.esa.int/navipedia/index.php/Transformations_between_ECEF_and_ENU_coordinates) The steps are simple

- Form a rotation matrix using the (lat, lon) calculated in step 1
- Multiply your (X,Y,Z) coordinates with the rotation matrix

In scalar form the above-mentioned matrix equations for ENU speed components are

```
E = -sin(lon) * x + cos(lon) * y
N = -cos(lon) * sin(lat) * x - sin(lon) * sin(lat) * y + cos(lat) * z
U = cos(lon) * cos(lat) * x + sin(lon) * cos(lat) * y + sin(lat) * z
```

The `lat` and `lon` are the Wgs84 position coordinates and `x`, `y` and `z` are the ECEF velocity coordinates.